# OpenStack for Django panel

Tags: python, django, forms, openstack, restful-architecture

I created a panel in open stack. What I want to do is produce a simple page that when loaded it makes a call to get a status and then puts that status (good, bad, warning) in a page with a combo box and have a submit button that when hit gets back to my python code so I can do what I want based on that status.

They way I did it was a form with a ChoiceField. I have a class IndexView (views.APIViews) from open stack I believe. It has a get_data method called where I can go get the data and return a context. I haven't found an example where you set the something in the context passing the status to a form somehow.  Like context['status'] = "Good"..
What I get is when the page is loaded get_data is called and I do nothing. The submit button is there but no "Status: (combo box)" I hit Submit and status is called with a POST. form.is_valid() is false and it returns a render with a form created passing in request.POST. This gets a form to appears and I can hit Submit and I get a call to status with a .POST and is_valid is true and it redirects to thanks like I want. It's just that I can't get data into the form in get_data.

Here is my code:

Views.py

```
from horizon import views
from django import forms
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ("GOOD", "Good"),
     ("BAD", "Bad"),
     ("COMPROMISED", "Compromised")
)

def thanks(request):
    return render(request, 'pinehurst_dashboard/ssa_panel/sent.html')

class SsaForm(forms.Form):
    status = forms.ChoiceField(choices = STATUS_CHOICES, label="Status:")

def status(request):
    print("STATUS CALLED method=",request.method)
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = SsaForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            # ...
            print("redirect to THANKS!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('thanks/') # Redirect after POST
        else:
            print("form.is_valid = false")
    else:
        print("Requesting form\n")
        form = SsaForm(initial = {"status", "BAD"}) # An unbound form

    return render(request, 'pinehurst_dashboard/ssa_panel/index.html', {
        'form': form,
    })

class IndexView(views.APIView):
    # A very simple class-based view...
    template_name = 'my_dashboard/ssa_panel/index.html'

    def get_data(self, request, context, *args, **kwargs):
        print("GET_DATA Called", context)
        # Add data to the context here...
        return context
```

Urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.conf.urls import url

from openstack_dashboard.dashboards.my_dashboard.ssa_panel import views


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'status/$', views.status),
    url(r'thanks/$', views.thanks),
)
```

nothing in models.py

my_dashboard/ssa_panel/index.html

```
{% extends 'pinehurst_dashboard/base.html' %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block title %}{% trans "Pinehurst" %}{% endblock %}

{% block page_header %}
  {% include "horizon/common/_page_header.html" with title=_("SSA Panel") %}
{% endblock page_header %}

{% block pinehurst_dashboard_main %}
<form action="status/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```